# Wpf- How can I get the TreeViewItem that triggered the TreeViewItem.Loaded event?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

I am trying to attach some handlers to each `TreeViewItem` as they are loaded and then remove the handlers as they are unloaded.

Here is the Code that I have in my custom control which inherits from `TreeView`:

```
public ModdedTreeView()
    {
        this.AddHandler(TreeViewItem.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ItemLoaded));            

        this.AddHandler(TreeViewItem.UnloadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ItemUnloaded));
    }

    protected void ItemLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;

        if (item == null)
            return;

        item.AddHandler(TreeViewItem.CollapsedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ItemCollapsed));

        item.AddHandler(TreeViewItem.ExpandedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ItemExpanded));

        item.AddHandler(TreeViewItem.SelectedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ItemSelected));
    }


    protected void ItemUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;

        if (item == null)
            return;

        item.RemoveHandler(TreeViewItem.CollapsedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ItemCollapsed));

        item.RemoveHandler(TreeViewItem.ExpandedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ItemExpanded));

        item.RemoveHandler(TreeViewItem.SelectedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ItemSelected));
    }
```

**Edit:**

I still can not figure out what is going on. It just seems to be picking up the `TreeView`  loaded event instead of the `TreeViewItem` loaded event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the TreeViewItem.Loaded event is a direct event. So there is no way to accomplish what I was trying.

Answer (score 0):

Loaded is a routed event, so you will find its source in the `OriginalSource` property, which should be the treeviewitem that triggered the event.

Comment: I've tried that. For some reason OriginalSource is always the TreeView not a TreeViewItem.